# how to visually design reports generated by dossier?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, dossier

I have used [dossier](https://github.com/adamhunter/dossier) to generate reports in my application. Now I want to visually design my reports generated by dossier like charts. Is there any gem available to do that? Can you please any one help me (or) tell me to how to use iReport in rails application.

Answer (score 0):

Dossier currently does not provide any visualizations (though that would be a nice enhancement).  I have been using to to power various JS charting libraries using JSON.  Any report can be converted to JSON format by adding a ".json" extension to the report url.  Generally I have found that I will have to alter the way I write the sequel selects slightly to get the right JSON output, but overall have had good success with this strategy.

Let me know if I can answer any other questions on this.

Thanks!